# Docker under WSL2 is running, but building container fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, wsl-2

I am trying to build a container to be deployed to AWS Lambda.

I have followed [the linked tutorial](https://blog.avenuecode.com/running-docker-engine-on-wsl-2) to install Docker under WSL2 (Windows 10 Pro, build 19045) with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

However, when trying to build the container I get an error:

[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you do `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`?

Comment: Yes. Did it again now to make sure and still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you restart the wsl terminal? What does `id` print?

Comment: @tkausl Oh, somehow I did not think of restarting WSL. It works!